# Density function of Beta distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $a, b, \alpha, β$ be real numbers such that $a <b, α> 0$ and $β> 0$. If the random variable $X$ is distributed beta with parameters $α$ and $β$, find the density function of the random variable $Y: = (b - a) X + a $.

This is my solution:
I know that the density function is
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}
$$
with $B(\alpha,\beta)=\displaystyle\int_0^{1}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} dx$.

And by a theorem (i don't know the name of the theorem)
$$
f_Y(y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             f_X(h^{-1}(x))\left|\frac{\partial(h^{-1}(x))}{\partial y}\right| &   if  & y=h(x) \\
             \\ 0 &  if & y\neq h(x) 
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$
So as $h(x)=(b-a)x+a$, we have $h^{-1}(y)=\frac{y-a}{b-a}=x$. Then $\frac{\partial(h^{-1}(x))}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{y-a}{b-a}\right)=\frac{1}{b-a}$.

Finally i have $$f_Y(y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
            \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\left(\frac{y-a}{b-a}\right)^{\alpha-1}\left(1-\frac{y-a}{b-a}\right)^{\beta-1} \left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)&   if  & y=h(x) \\
             \\ 0 &  if & y\neq h(x) 
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$
is okey my solution? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that since $X\in(0, 1)$ and $Y=(b-a)X+a$, then the image of $(0,1)$ is $(a,b)$. These are the values that the random variable $Y$ can take. So instead of saying $y=h(x)$ you could put the actual bounds of Y like this:

$$g(Y)=\begin{cases}\frac{(Y-a)^{\alpha-1}(b-Y)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)(b-a)^{\alpha+\beta-1}}&\text {if } a<Y<b\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: your idea is great and simple. I understand that you need to divide by the beta function, right?

Comment: @Juan Yes lol! I got so focused on the other terms that I left it out.